# ArcGIS Online and Field Maps

Tags: arcgis-online, offline, arcgis-field-maps, map-notes

I have some data collection I am trying to do in the field, so I thought field maps by Esri would be perfect.

I have made some area polygons on ArcGIS Online maps using the "map notes" feature to outline places I want to go. The data collection I am performing is in remote locations, so I wanted to download my maps offline for the field map application.

For some reason none of my polygons I created, or the "map notes," are able to download offline and sync to the field maps.

Is this something that is not available to do, or does it have to do with licensing?

I have looked everywhere to find a sync option for the map notes, but I cannot find one.

The error message says:

> Several items in this map need to be updated to enable offline mode

The detailed error says:

> Sync is not enabled

Comment: Make sure you follow this before going to the field with Field Maps or any other ESRI field apps. https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/field-maps/field-mobility/create-a-map-for-data-collection-in-field-maps/
https://learn.arcgis.com/en/paths/try-data-collection/

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I tried to do what you show in your screenshot, but there is no "editing" tab available with the enable sync option under settings in the AGOL. For other projects it is available, but for my polygons it disappears so I am unable to click on it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the layer in your contents section on AGOL, click on the settings tab,

[image: Settings]

scroll down to Feature Layer (hosted) and tick on Editing and Enable Sync

[image: sync]

Comment: I finally figured it out! I did not realize what a "hosted" feature layer meant, and there was no toggle option for enabling sync for all of my unhosted feature layers. I figured out I can publish them and make them hosted, thus enabling sync. Your comment made it all click, I cannot thank you enough :)